# MySQL 5.1.73 change default log location

Tags: mysql, error-log

How do you change the default location of the log_error file?  If you point it to a new path, will it automatically move the existing file? Or will it create a new file, and the original file can be deleted?  Software is installed on Windows.

Also, how do you change the default location of the innodb log files?

Answer (score 0):

**A). To change Mysql innodb_log file to a new location.**

```
 1. Change my.cnf settings for innodb_log file or innodb_fast_shutdown=0 
   (so it does full flush of log files from buffer).

 2. Stop mysql.

 3. Change innodb_log_group_home_dir = /mysql/new_location/ in my.cnf.

 4. Start Mysql, it should be up now.
```

**B). To change Mysql log_error file to a new location.**

```
 1. Create a new file for log_error file OS level. 
     - copy nul > /mysql/NEW_LOCATION/mysql_error
     - Give mysql permission to /mysql/NEW_LOCATION/mysql_error to read and write.

 2. Change my.cnf log_error = /mysql/NEW_LOCATION/mysql_error 

 3. Stop Mysql.

 4. Start Mysql.
```

*You may do A and B in one shot, I will let you do organize which ever way you wanted.*

Comment: Some of that is the wrong syntax for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Some file are easy to move, some are not.  And the mechanisms have changed in subsequent versions.  5.1 is so antique, that I do not have ready access to 5.1.  Can you provide the current names of the log(s) you want to move?  Also run this to see what settings are available:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%file%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%dir%';
```

What version of Windows?  In older versions, you could move a file and build a "Junction" (aka "soft link" to it).  Newer versions have a better mechanism for that.